# find the lengths of all sublists containing common repeated element

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing, repeat, sublist

I need to find all the sublists from a list where the element is 'F' and that must come one after other

`g= ['T','F','F,'F','F','T','T','T','F,'F','F','T]`

so, here in this case there are two sublists present in this list which contains element `'F'` in repeat

```
i.e; ['F','F,'F','F'] in index 1,2,3,4 which is in repeat ,so answer is 4
and
['F','F,'F'] in index 8,9,10 which is again in continuous index,so answer is 3
```

Note:
The list contains only two elements `'T'` and `'F'` and every time we are doing these operations for element `'F'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the lengths of consecutive sequences with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ['T','F','F','F','F','T','T','T','F','F','F','T']

# Consecutive sequences of "F".
#   "groupby(data)" produces an iterator that calculates on-the-fly.
#   The iterator returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable "data".
seqs = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(data) if k == 'F']
print(seqs)
# [['F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], ['F', 'F', 'F']]
seq_lens = [len(k) for k in seqs]
print(seq_lens)
# [4, 3]
```

Also cool is max length of such consecutive sequences:

```
max_len_seq = len(max(seqs, key=len))
print(max_len_seq)
# 4
```

See [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for more info:

```
class groupby:
    # [k for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')] --> A B C D A B
    # [list(g) for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCD')] --> AAAA BBB CC D
    ...
    etc
```

Comment: It works, but prob. miss the answer? *find-the-lengths-of-all-sublists-containing-common repeated element*?   Add this ```groups_size = [len(item) for item in seqs]``` <-- *[4, 3]*   +1 still for *groupby*

Comment: Oh my, should I edit my answer?

Comment: To be nit-picky, it should be stated - *Make an ```iterator``` that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable*  and not " produces an on-the-fly iterable..."

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 variable to keep count of the repeated letter. Traverse the array and when you found t increase t, when you find a f check the tcount first if it is bigger than 1 it means there is a repeat print the count of the repetition.

```
tcount = 0;
fcount = 0;
for e in g:
   if e=="T":
      tcount++
      if fcount>1
         print(fcount)
      fcount=0
  //do same operation for F
```